# ruby irb call Fixnum#+ every time the enter was hit?

Tags: ruby, irb

```
class Fixnum
        alias :old_plus :+
        def +(value)
                puts "self is:#{self}"
                self.old_plus(value)
        end
end
```

if you open irb and do a monkey patch as above, then every time you hit enter, it will print some random number like:

```
2.0.0p195 :019 >
self is:18
self is:116
self is:19
self is:17
self is:0
```

It is weird for me as only a Fixnum object can call the function :+. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Call `raise` in your `+` method and you'll get a nice backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

IRB itself is written in Ruby, so monkey patches to core classes can affect it likes yours did. That should tell you that this sort of patch is not a good idea. If you changed the return value to something else, things could break easily.